# c++ system() hangs on using netcat to connect to socket in different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, system, freeze

I'm starting a simple socket server on a separate thread, and trying to connect to it using `netcat` on the main thread. This is the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void* callback(void*);

bool isServerReady = false;

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int result = pthread_create(&thread, 0, callback, 0);
    if (result != 0) {
        cout << "[ERROR] Unable to create thread" << endl;
    }

    while (!isServerReady) {
    }

    int returnValue = system("echo TEST | netcat localhost 1234");
    cout << "Return value: " << returnValue << endl;
    return 0;
}

void* callback(void* threadId)
{
    int serverSocketId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (serverSocketId == -1) {
        cout << "[SERVER ERROR] Unable to create server socket." << endl;
        return (void*)-1;
    }

    int serverPort = 1234;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(serverPort);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int bindReturn = bind(serverSocketId, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    if (bindReturn == -1) {
        cout << "[SERVER ERROR] Unable to bind server socket." << endl;
        return (void*) -1;
    }

    isServerReady = true;

    int waitQueueSize = 5;
    listen(serverSocketId, waitQueueSize);

    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
    socklen_t clientAddressSize = sizeof(clientAddress);
    int clientSocketId = accept(serverSocketId, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &clientAddressSize);
    if (clientSocketId == -1) {
        cout << "[SERVER ERROR] Unable to create client socket." << endl;
        return (void*)-1;
    }

    char clientBuffer[256];
    bzero(clientBuffer, 256);
    int charsRead = read(clientSocketId, clientBuffer, 255);
    if (charsRead == -1) {
        cout << "[SERVER ERROR] Unable to read client socket." << endl;
        return (void*)-1;
    }

    string serverMessage = "You wrote: ";
    serverMessage.append(clientBuffer);
    int charsWritten = write(clientSocketId, (char*)serverMessage.c_str(), (int)serverMessage.length());
    if (charsWritten == -1) {
        cout << "[SERVER ERRROR] Error writing to client socket." << endl;
        return (void*)-1;
    }

    int closeReturn = close(serverSocketId);
    if (closeReturn == -1) {
        cout << "[SERVER ERROR] Error closing server socket." << endl;
        return (void*)-1;
    }

    return (void*)0;
}
```

However, the `system` function never returns, making the program hang: the server's response `"You wrote: TEST"` is correctly printed on the console, but after that the program just hangs, without reaching the line that prints the return value. If I extract the same server code into another program, launch it, and use the same `netcat` call from the command line, I get the same response message, and then `netcat` exits without me being required to do anything.

This is the compilation command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -lpthread && ./test
```

and compiler version:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4
```

Why do you think `netcat` is not returning when called from inside `system()`?

Comment: I think the part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13482079/3962537) talking about the client invocation of netcat is relevant to your issue.

Comment: You don't close the clientSocketId.

Comment: Just interested as to why you use POSIX threads instead of C++ threads? Also, you don't declare `isServerReady` as volatile?

Comment: Thanks for you remarks, this is just a quick and dirty experiment taken out of a bigger program, and C++ is not my main programming language, so I'm still learning the new C++ 11/14 features :)

Comment: @kfsone Thanks! That was it :)

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks for your suggestion. However, I couldn't find any implementation of `nc` (I'm testing Ubuntu and Fedora virtual machines) where the `-c` option is supported. Anyway, as kfsone suggested, I just had to manually close the client socket from within my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @kfsone, the problem was just that my server never closed the client socket, thus preventing the client `netcat` to realize that the server wasn't listening any more, and making it wait for no reason indefinitely. To solve this:

```
// ...
string serverMessage = "You wrote: ";
serverMessage.append(clientBuffer);
int charsWritten = write(clientSocketId, (char*)serverMessage.c_str(), (int)serverMessage.length());
if (charsWritten == -1) {
    cout << "[SERVER ERRROR] Error writing to client socket." << endl;
    return (void*)-1;
}

// ADDED THIS:
int closeClientReturn = close(clientSocketId);
if (closeClientReturn == -1) {
    cout << "[SERVER ERROR] Error closing client socket." << endl;
    return (void*)-1;
}

int closeReturn = close(serverSocketId);
if (closeReturn == -1) {
    cout << "[SERVER ERROR] Error closing server socket." << endl;
    return (void*)-1;
}

return (void*)0;
```